# Shared Data Extension Not visible under Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sfmc-business-unit

I am trying to create a **Shared Data Extension** to use across multiple Business Units.

Documentation says to follow these steps
1.Click Subscribers.
2.Click Shared Data Extension.
3.Select the data extension name.
4.Click Permissions.

But when I click on Subscribers, the entry **Shared Data Extension** itself is not available in the left side panel. 
Is this a permission issue ? 
Or do we need to contact SFMC support to enable this feature ? 
Is there any way to create a Shared DE from Email Studio ? 
Or can we convert an existing DE to a shared one ?

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

In Subscribers Panel, you have the folder "Shared Items", where all DEs that are shared are located.

- You can move a DE from the local "Data Extensions" folder, to the folder "Shared Items".
- And you can also create a shared DE by selecting a location in the folder "Shared Items/Shared Data Extensions/"

[image]

Comment: @Mahoud Gueye I tried creating a new DE to put it under Shared Items. But `Shared Items` option itself in not available for selection while changing the location. [![SharedItemSelectionNotAvailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY2va.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY2va.jpg) Any idea why ?

Comment: @amal if you aren't able to see the folder "shared Items", create a Case, or contact your Account Executive

Answer (score 0):

please check if your user has the permission to view the Shared Data Extension folder?

[image]